# Random outOfMemory crashes in my app when running on some devices but not all devices

Tags: android

I am facing a strange problem.My e-Commerce app fetches products data from the server.Each product has image and other details.It inflates all good on all devices that I have with me.To name them, nexus7, samsung note, sony experia.

The problem, when my client runs the app on same devices, he gets random OutOfMemory error.And, I didn't got this error even once.

I am looking for some idea for how to approach this problem.Please let me know, if I need to provide any other piece of information.Please help, however you can.Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it happens on devices which runs Android gingerbread version : I have faced OutOfMemory errors due to Bitmap different management in memory on gingerbread.

Comment: One issue could be deep nested layout structure. See if you have too many nested laytouts. Tack this to the page where your client is getting the crash. I had this issue once, and once I re structured my layout more efficiently it started working. Another similar issue I face when I had a custom TextView and in one screen I was using it like too many times; weird but when I stopped using the custom TextView crashes stopped.

Comment: How are you managing the display of your images?  https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html